# howto get students that dont have user account

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with one to many relationships. Students and Users. There's a relationship table in the middle called students_users which contains student.id and user.id. What I need is to get **how many students don't have a user account** created yet. I'm using hibernate and my repositories extend CrudRepository. It's a spring boot application. What is the best way to achieve that? Getting a list of all my employees and checking in the relationships table if the student.id already exits? That would sound exhausting to me if I had a large database. I don't know how to create that query in spring boot so I need a little help. Thanks in advance

PS: The students_users table doesn't have an entity. Its created by the ManyToOne annotation

Comment: The fact that you use Hibernate doesn't mean you cannot use SQL. Just write a SQL query as you otherwise would do.

Comment: You can write HQL as well

Comment: Adding to M Deinum and Akshay, you can take a look at this - https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/

Comment: Just did it. Add @Query in the repository class. It works like a charm. Thanks